# Synergy maps the space bar to character "s"

Tags: synergy

I have Synergy 1.4.12 with Windows7 as server and Mac OSX Mountain Lion as client.
While focusing the Mac screen, if I press the space bar, the Mac interpret it as an "s" in all apps.

I confirmed this with the keyboard viewer: when pressing space bar, it highlights the "s" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a fix for this.

I ended up uninstalling synergy in the MacBook (client) and installing [SynergyKM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergykm/). I didn't get the weird behavior anymore.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.